# how to edit custom fields of type gallery from front-end

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

i have added custom field name "gallery-photos" and type gallery .

but i am unable to edit it in front end using your plugin

i tried using :

but i it just show array.

Please guide me how to do it

Comment: What is "your plugin"? Are you asking someone specific? I don't think this is a relevant question here.

Comment: i want to do it from wordpress code